# Firebird ISC 335544334 - Conversion error from string "2002-07-07 22:00:00.000"

Tags: sql, excel, import, firebird, razorsql

I am currently working on a project which allows you to import data from an Excel file. I use the Programm RazorSQL. But every time I start the import, the

ISC error code 335544334 occures ->

```
An error occurred: java.sql.SQLException: conversion error from 
string "2002-07-07 22:00:00.000" [SQLState:22018, ISC error 
code:335544334]
```

Does Firebird use some special Date formats? I really need an answer, it's very important. This problem keeps me waiting to continue with my work...

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the data, what is the DDL of the target table and what is the **full** exception stacktrace?

Comment: Also please explain exactly how you are importing the data.

Comment: In any case, the most common cause for this is attempting to insert this value into a field that has a type other than `timestamp`.

Comment: "Help people to help you".
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html and even http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that Firebird tried to convert the string value `2002-07-07 22:00:00.000` to a datatype other than `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` and did not succeed because the string value is invalid for the target datatype. The format as shown will correctly convert to a `TIMESTAMP`, which means that you are assigning this either to the wrong column, or the column has the wrong type. For example, a `DATE` has no time component in dialect 3, so converting a string with a time component will fail with this error, as will converting to a numerical column (`INTEGER`, `BIGINT`, etc).

Without more information about the columns involved and the exact method of import, it is not possible to provide a more specific answer.